# If $x\in A$, $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$, can I write $x\in A\cap B\backslash C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be arbitrary sets. Further, suppose that there exists some element $x$ that belongs to $A$ and $B$ but does not belong to $C$. Formally, $x\in A$, $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$.

Can I then write $x\in A\cap B\backslash C$ or should I instead write something like $x\in\{A\cap B\}\backslash C$?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram. See whether $(A\cap B)\setminus C=A\cap(B\setminus C)$.

Comment: You should definitely NOT write $x\in\{A\cap B\}\backslash C$. The expression $\{A\cap B\}$ denotes a set with only one element: the intersection of $A$ and $B$. That's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both notations apply:
\begin{align*}
(A\cap B)\backslash C = (A\cap B)\cap C^{c} = A\cap (B\cap C^{c}) = A\cap(B\backslash C)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: When you write $C^c$, what set does that mean? You need to choose a universal set for this notation to be defined.

Comment: @KyleMiller Indeed, you are right. Here I suppose the universal set is tacitly known.

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful to know the precise definitions of the sets under consideration. Given sets $X$ and $Y$, the set $X\cap Y$ is defined to be the set that satisfies the following property:
$$ \text{for all $x$, } x\in X\cap Y \text{ is equivalent to } x\in X\text{ and }x\in Y.
$$
This is all we need to work with this set $X\cap Y$.  Also, given sets $X$ and $Y$, the set $X\setminus Y$ is defined to be the set that satisfies the following property:
$$ \text{for all $x$, } x\in X\setminus Y \text{ is equivalent to } x\in X\text{ and }x\not\in Y.
$$
Again, this is all we need to work with $X\setminus Y$. (Note there's an equivalent definition $X\setminus Y=\{x\in X\mid x\not\in Y\}$.)

Hence, $A\cap B\setminus C$ (or $(A\cap B)\setminus C$ if you want to use parentheses to make the order of operations clear) is the set with the following property, after using the above two rules:
$$ \text{for all $x$, } x\in A\cap B\setminus C \text{ is equivalent to } x\in A\text{, }x\in B\text{, and }x\not\in C.
$$
An intermediate step here is "$x\in A\cap B$ and $x\not\in C$."